# How to transform command into keymap

Tags: vim, keymapping

In my `.vimrc`, I have the following command definition:

```
command! -range Runit <line1>,<line2> python3 RunLine(<line1>, <line2>)
```

and it works fine.

I'd like to have it as keymap.

I tried several ways to

```
noremap <F2> :call
```

the function with arguments but no result. Maybe someone can point me to a solution.

Comment: We would need to see what you actually tried in order to help you fix it.